# Response() not respecting API resource structure

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I have a strange (at least to my tired eyes) problem where using the `response()` function to return an API resource is ignoring the `with()` method of said resource, and also not adding the 'data' key wrapping. Strangely the latter issue is only on single resources, not on collections.

I'm using Laravel 5.7.

The method using the `response()` function is in my API controller, which is extended by my other controllers.

Interestingly using `$data->response()` works, but I'd then the respond method would only be able to accept collections / models / resources, and not an array for example - which I rely on for other methods that call `respond()`, like my `respondWithError()` method.

**ApiController**

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function respond($data, int $status_code = 200)
    {
        try {
            // this is where the issue is
            // simply returning $data prevents the issue
            return response($data)->setStatusCode($status_code);
        } catch (Throwable $t) {
            $this->logger->log('critical', $t->getMessage(), ['exception' => $t]);
            return $this->respondWithError(500);
        }
    }
...
}
```

**ClubController**

```
use App\Http\Resources\Club as ClubResource;
use App\Http\Resources\ClubCollection;
...

class ClubController extends ApiController
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return ClubCollection
     */
    public function index()
    {
       // returns with data key wrapping, but ignores the with() method on the resource
      // collection
       return $this->respond(new ClubCollection(Club::all()));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {

         // returns with no wrapping, and also doesn't implement resource with() method
            return $this->respond(new ClubResource(Club::findOrFail($id)));
    }
...
}
```

**ClubCollection Resource**

```
class ClubCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data'  => $this->collection,
            'links' => [
                'self'  => 'link-value'
            ],
            'status'    => 'success'
        ];
    }

    // doesn't get called
    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'test' => 'this will be ignored '
        ];
    }
}
```

**ClubResource**

```
class Club extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'                => $this->id,
            'name'              => $this->name,
            'primary_color'     => $this->primary_colour,
            'secondary_colour'  => $this->secondary_colour,
            'tertiary_colour'   => $this->tertiary_colour,
            'logo_url'          => $this->logo_url,
            'narrative'         => $this->narrative
        ];
    }

    // doesn't get called
    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'status'    => 'success'
        ];
    }

}
```

To clarify, neither the index or show endpoints result in the `with()` method being called. More importantly, the `show()` method also returns the data flat, with no 'data' key wrapping it.

**api/v1/clubs/1 returns:**

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Johns Ltd",
"primary_color": "18,140,142",
"secondary_colour": "13,148,5",
"tertiary_colour": "187,18,162",
"logo_url": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?58550",
"narrative": "Consequatur veniam consectetur sint blanditiis. Minima fugiat voluptatem aperiam corporis assumenda et consequuntur. Voluptate fugiat nulla eos ut. Itaque vero doloribus ea nihil consequuntur vel. Minus error quos occaecati dignissimos."
}
```

**Expected return:**

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Johns Ltd",
    "primary_color": "18,140,142",
    "secondary_colour": "13,148,5",
    "tertiary_colour": "187,18,162",
    "logo_url": "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?58550",
    "narrative": "Consequatur veniam consectetur sint blanditiis. Minima fugiat voluptatem aperiam corporis assumenda et consequuntur. Voluptate fugiat nulla eos ut. Itaque vero doloribus ea nihil consequuntur vel. Minus error quos occaecati dignissimos."
},
"status": "success"
}
```

Comment: verified if is a json valid

Comment: change this  `return response()->json(["data" => $data, 'status' => $status_code]);`

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos then when the index() method is called, which returns a ResourceCollection, I'll get the data doubled wrapped with 'data' keys. Plus that won't solve the issue of the with() method not being called. Note that I mentioned the unexpected removal of the data key only happens with single resources.

Comment: im see error you need `collection` to `Array` here put `  `return $this->respond(new ClubCollection(Club::all()->toArray()));` you try insert `collection` on `array` need convert to push

Comment: Please re-read the question. The data wrapping is fine on the index method. Where are you seeing any method that requires an array anyway? Converting the collection to an array makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

To send the response like you want

```
return response()->json(["data" => $data, 'status'=>$status], $code);
```

`$code` is the response code it can be 404,500,200 as per you requirement

Comment: Defeats the point of using resources though surely? The whole point is to abstract the formatting into a resource

Comment: changed it, check now and can you please elaborate what you are asking!

Comment: for reference you can check this one [Http response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses)

Comment: if someone is gonna ask what is 2+2 then everyone is gonna say 4 @AlexanderVillalobos

Comment: I'm asking why when using response($data), the wrapping that comes automatically with a resource is being removed for single resources, but not for collections, and why for both the with() method is ignored

Answer (score 0):

Resources have their own way of returning responses via the `response()` method.

Note: by `response()` method, I am referencing the `->response()` inside the Resource class, not the helper global function `response()`

for example: `(new ClubCollection(Club::all()))->response()->setStatusCode(200);`

You could add an exit statement at the top of your respond method

```
public function respond($data, int $status_code = 200)
{

    if ($data instanceof JsonResource) {
        return $data->response()->setStatusCode($status_code);
    }
    try {
        // this is where the issue is
        // simply returning $data prevents the issue
        return response($data)->setStatusCode($status_code);
    } catch (Throwable $t) {
        $this->logger->log('critical', $t->getMessage(), ['exception' => $t]);
        return $this->respondWithError(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain "Resources have their own way of returning responses via the response() method."?

Comment: If you new up a resource, for example: `new ClubCollection(Club::all())` you can then `return (new ClubCollection(Club::all()))->response()->setStatusCode(200);` (or omit the setStatusCode as it defaults to 200). So if you add an `instanceof` check in the response function you can return the ->response() method instead of using the global helper response() with an array inside it.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't help with my actual question - plus I want to abstract as much of the code into my ApiController as possible as you can see from the sample code.

Comment: The modified `respond` method I supplied in my answer would detect that you are trying to send a kind of Resource and properly return it in the correct format. It should allow the `with` methods to work properly and it will also be wrapped in the `data` array